# How to add META-INF/context.xml in Warbler

Tags: warbler, context.xml, meta-inf

How can I add META-INF/context.xml into the war? I didn't find any config entry in config/warble.rb.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Nick's method doesn't work. The file is actually copied to WEB-INF/META-INF/context.xml.

I finally figure out a way to copy context.xml to META-INF:

1. create META-INF/context.xml under your rails app root folder
2. uncomment and change the following line in config/warble.rb

   `config.public_html = FileList["public/**/*", "doc/**/*", "META-INF/context.xml" ]`

Basically treat META-INF as public_html, and it will be copied to webapps/youapp/META-INF.

Comment: FWIW, to make it slightly simpler you can just add to the defaults:
`config.public_html += FileList["META-INF/context.xml"]`

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add one yourself. You can either create a `META-INF/context.xml` directory and file in your project and add `META-INF` to `config.dirs` in `config/warble.rb` or you can add a "pathmap" to rename the context.xml file into the META-INF directory in the war file.

```
config.pathmaps.application += ["%{context.xml,META-INF/context.xml}p"]
```

Comment: The above method doesn't work. The file is actually copied to WEB-INF/META-INF/context.xml.
I finally figure out a way to copy context.xml to META-INF: 
1. create META-INF/context.xml under your rails app root folder
2. uncomment and change the following line in config/warble.rb
  config.public_html = FileList["public/**/*", "doc/**/*", "META-INF/context.xml" ]

Basically treat META-INF as public_html, and it will be copied to webapps/youapp/META-INF.

Answer (score 0):

A better way of tackling this might be to use the following in your `warble.rb` file.

```
config.script_files << 'path_to_file/context.xml'
```

See documentation towards bottom of https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/lib/warbler/config.rb

```
# These file will be placed in the META-INF directory of the jar or war that warbler
# produces. They are primarily used as launchers by the runnable feature.
attr_accessor :script_files
```